# Install the latest version of usb_modeswitch on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, internet, modem, usb-modeswitch

How can I install to the latest of usb_modeswitch ( currently version 2.2.5). The version I have on Ubuntu is 2.1.1 I am on Ubuntu 14.04 and do not want to upgrade to 15.10.

Comment: please help without a modem i don't have any way to connect to the internet

Comment: no one could help me so i have to switch back to windows , what a pity¡